# How to send a gif image in bot framework without using sourceEvent

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

I am trying to send a GIF image using the bot framework across all platforms. I dont want to use sourceEvent to send custom GIFS across each platform separately. My current code looks as shown below

Hi, first of all , thanks for the fabulous effort in maintaining this library. I want to send a GIF across all channels and read about AnimationCard in the documentation repo

My code looks like this

```
function onMessage(session) {
    var msg = new builder.Message(session).addAttachment(createAnimationCard(session, 'title', 'subtitle', 'text'));
    session.send(msg);
}

function createAnimationCard(session, title, subtitle, text) {
    return new builder.AnimationCard(session)
        .title(title)
        .subtitle(subtitle)
        .text(text)
        .media([
            new builder.MediaUrl()
                .profile('GIF test')
                .url('http://media2.giphy.com/media/FiGiRei2ICzzG/giphy.gif')
        ])
}
```

How I get this error saying

```
TypeError: builder.AnimationCard is not a constructor
    at createAnimationCard (D:\bots\fastrivia\index.js:65:12)
    at Array.onMessage (D:\bots\fastrivia\index.js:60:58)
    at SimpleDialog.waterfallAction [as fn] (D:\bots\fastrivia\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\DialogAction.js:131:25)
    at SimpleDialog.begin (D:\bots\fastrivia\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\SimpleDialog.js:15:14)
    at Session.beginDialog (D:\bots\fastrivia\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\Session.js:180:16)
    at routeToDialog (D:\bots\fastrivia\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\Session.js:421:23)
    at D:\bots\fastrivia\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\Session.js:449:29
    at D:\bots\fastrivia\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\Session.js:505:25
    at ActionSet.recognizeAction (D:\bots\fastrivia\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\ActionSet.js:44:9)
    at D:\bots\fastrivia\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\Session.js:501:43
```

It seems there is no AnimationCard under cards package in the botframework lib when I checked under node_modules. What is the best way to send a GIF across all platforms on the bot framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that the bits for using `AnimationCard` in `Node.js` are not yet public so I believe you will need to install the pre-release version of BotBuilder:

```
npm install --save botbuilder@next
```

Comment: thanks for the input, i did that and could use the AnimationCard, however there is one issue, it has a function media() that accepts a MediaUrl array it seems at https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/reference/#animationcard but I cannnot find the class MediaUrl anywhere, any ideas

Answer (score 1):

your code is perfectly fine, just replace the `new builder.MediaUrl()` with an object. It's often the case, that structures that as simple as MediaUrl have to be directly initialized and do not have a constructor in the framework.

```
function createAnimationCard(session, title, subtitle, text) {
    return new builder.AnimationCard(session)
        .title(title)
        .subtitle(subtitle)
        .text(text)
        .media([{ profile: 'GIF test',
                  url: 'http://media2.giphy.com/media/FiGiRei2ICzzG/giphy.gif'
        }])
}
```